# Estou tentando instalar o isotope no meu site

Tags: html

Estou instalando o Isotope, mas por algum motivo fazer ele funcionar

```
<div class="container-fluid ">
  <div class="row pt-5">
    <div class="col-md-8 menu-prod mx-auto" id="filter-buttons" > 
      <a href="#" data-filter="*" class="pr-3">TODOS </a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".bilhar" class="pr-3">BILHAR </a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".pebolim">PEBOLIM </a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".ping-pong" class="pr-3">PING-PONG</a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".carteado-xadrez" class="pr-3">CARTEADO & XADREZ</a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".tamancobol" class="pr-3">TAMANCOBOL</a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".bocha" class="pr-3">BOCHA</a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".bocha">AERO HOCKEY</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<!-- produtos -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row " id="filter-container">


    <figure class="bilhar col-xs-12 col-md-4 ">
      <a href=""><img src="imgs/produtos/mesa/modelomesa.jpg"></a>
    </figure>

    <figure class="pebolim col-xs-12 col-md-4 ">
      <a href=""><img src="imgs/produtos/mesa/modelomesa.jpg"></a>
    </figure>


  </div>
</div>
```

**no arquivo js**

```
var $container = $('#filter-container');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : 'figure',
        filter: '*',
        resizable: false,
        animationEngine: 'jquery'
    });
});

// filter buttons

$('#filter-buttons a').click(function(){

    // select current
    var $optionSet = $(this).parents('#filter-buttons');
    $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
});
```

Como estou trabalhando com Bootstrap, esses são os arquivo que estão linkados:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- isotope -->
<script src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: "mas por algum motivo fazer ele funcionar" essa frase não fez sentido

Comment: escrevi errado desculpe, por algum motivo não consigo fazer o isotope funcionar

Comment: Consegue elaborar um [mcve]?

Comment: *Aparentemente* o problema parece estar em **`$container.imagesLoaded`**, onde está chamando o **js** deste plugin **imagesLoaded**?

Comment: Obrigada LeAndrade era realmente o problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando uma função que não existe: `.imagesLoaded`. Provavelmente você pegou esse código em algum lugar e não carregou a biblioteca ou função que usa o `.imagesLoaded`. Com isso resulta em erro e o resto do código não é executado.

Você precisa carregar outro plugin **[imagesLoaded](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/)**:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

**Veja:**

```js
var $container = $('#filter-container');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : 'figure',
        filter: '*',
        resizable: false,
        animationEngine: 'jquery'
    });
});

// filter buttons

$('#filter-buttons a').click(function(){

    // select current
    var $optionSet = $(this).parents('#filter-buttons');
    $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.6/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid ">
  <div class="row pt-5">
    <div class="col-md-8 menu-prod mx-auto" id="filter-buttons" > 
      <a href="#" data-filter="*" class="pr-3">TODOS </a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".bilhar" class="pr-3">BILHAR </a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".pebolim">PEBOLIM </a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".ping-pong" class="pr-3">PING-PONG</a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".carteado-xadrez" class="pr-3">CARTEADO & XADREZ</a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".tamancobol" class="pr-3">TAMANCOBOL</a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".bocha" class="pr-3">BOCHA</a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".bocha">AERO HOCKEY</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<!-- produtos -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row " id="filter-container">


    <figure class="bilhar col-xs-12 col-md-4 ">
      <a href=""><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MlMdaB4-Kp0ZEHW2zjpiazAQCv2eCOb8SBivva8QJfoW1teFePHVdppLBeIffNDGy8L-=w100"></a>
    </figure>

    <figure class="pebolim col-xs-12 col-md-4 ">
      <a href=""><img src="https://carlinbilhares.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/PEBOLIM-DE-MADEIRA-1-100x100.jpg"></a>
    </figure>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada realmente peguei o código de um antigo projeto meu, como faz muito tempo não trabalho na área, não lembrava como tinha feito e não estava conseguindo executar o isotope mesmo pegando do site do desenvolvedor. Obrigado a todos